# how to generate the "exchange" map a.k.a. "swap" map

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, octave

I am looking for an easy way to generate a simple linear map in Octave.  The matrix I need, call it *sigma(n)*, is defined by the following property:  for all matrices *A* and *B* (both of dimension n) we have the equation:
`sigma(n) * kron(A,B) = kron(B,A) * sigma(n)`

For example,
`sigma(2) = [1,0,0,0; 0,0,1,0; 0,1,0,0; 0,0,0,1]`.

Is there a simple function for `sigma(n)`?

For my purposes *n* will be fairly small,  less than 50, so efficiency is not a concern.

*EDIT: now with the correct defining equation*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise it's bad form to answer one's own question, but with a small amount of head scratching I managed to generate the matrix explicitly:

```
function sig = sigma_(n) 
  sig = zeros(n^2,n^2);
  for i = 0:(n-1)
    for j = 0:(n-1)
      sig(i*n + j + 1, i+ (j*n) + 1) = 1;
    endfor
  endfor
endfunction
```

If anyone has a neater way to do this, I'm still interested.

Comment: +1 - never wrong to answer your own question, just be sure to thank those who also contributed answers (through a comment or up-voting their answers). Also, please be sure to mark the answer with the check-mark.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question!

I don't think that what you are asking is exactly possible. However, the two kronecker products are similar, via a permutation matrix, i.e., one has:

```
kron(A,B) = P kron(B,A) P^{-1}
```

This permutation matrix is such that the value of `Px` is obtained by putting x in a matrix row by row, and stacking the columns of that resulting matrix together.

**Edit** A proof that you are asking is not possible. Consider the matrices

```
A = 1 1       B = 1 0
    1 1           0 0
```

Then the two kronecker products are:

```
1 1 0 0      1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0      0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0      1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0      0 0 0 0
```

Suppose you multiply the first matrix on the left by *any* matrix sigma: the last two columns will stay at zero, so the result *cannot* be equal to the second matrix. QED.

Comment: The required matrix certainly does exist, (for completely general reasons) and with the right indexing scheme it's rather easy to write down.  As you hint, it is a permutation matrix.  My question was how to write a short function to get Octave to produce the matrix explicitly.

Comment: How embarrassing -- you are quite correct.  My mistake was in the question: the required property is that `sig * kron(A,B) = kron(B,A) * sig`, exactly as you describe above.  I will fix it.